# How to substring a variable with a variable? [BATCH]

Tags: batch-file

So i'm trying to substring a variable with another variable that has the number i want to substring it with but it doesn't work. I know it does work somehow as i have seen other people use it.

This is my code:

```
set total=%input:~0,%position%%
```

Where *Total* is the output and *Input* is the input, and *Position* is the amount of characters i want to substring.
The output i get is: **Position%**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nested variables are a problem, use EnableDelayedExpansion to circumvent it.

```
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set input=Hello world
set position=5

set total=!input:~0,%position%!

echo %total%
```